# getting List data from ViewData in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewdata

i am trying to get List of data from View Data 
Here is the method which is getting list of all clients from database

```
public List<ClientsModels> GetAllClients()
        {
            String conStr = conn.GetAccessConnString();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

                    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);
                    List<ClientsModels> allClientsList = new List<ClientsModels>();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        allClientsList.Add(new ClientsModels()
                        {
                            UserID = Convert.ToString(reader["userID"]),
                            Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
                            Email = Convert.ToString(reader["Email"]),
                            Phone = Convert.ToString(reader["Phone"])


                        });
                    }

                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                    return allClientsList;
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is the controller

```
public ActionResult Customers()
        {
            GetSetData data = new GetSetData();

            ViewData["AllClients"] = data.GetAllClients();

          return View();
        }
```

and here is the view

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/NewMaster.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Customers
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <%: ViewData["AllClients"].ToString() %>

</asp:Content>
```

this returns me

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication5.Models.ClientsModels]
```

the question is how can i get all the data one by one which is in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast `ViewData["AllClients"]` as `List<ClientsModels>` as then use a loop.

Use

```
<% foreach (var clientsModel in ViewData["AllClients"] as List<MvcApplication5.Models.ClientsModels>){ %>
    <label><%= clientsModel.Name %></label>                     
<% } %>
```

Comment: its says List<ClientsModels> could not be found. do i need to create a strongly typed view for this model ?

Comment: @AdilWaqar, Add proper namespace of your class like `List<YourAppicationNamespace.ClientsModels>`